# I'm trying to upload an image to Amazon S3 bucket, which was successful and after few uploads image isn't uploading

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, upload

When I try to upload an image after some successful upload, it isn't uploading my image and printing different identity pool id in my console and displaying this error:

> error1 Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSCognitoIdentityErrorDomain Code=10 "(null)" UserInfo={__type=ResourceNotFoundException, message=Identity 'us-east-2:********-****-****-****-************' not found.}

Any help is much appreciated, Thank you!

Comment: There is insufficient information in your question for us to assist you. For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: im making and app which needs to upload images to amazon s3 bucket, which i succesfully implemented and images are uploaded, but after sometime images aren't uploading and my console is priting different identity pool id which isnt mine, giving the error message which i metioned in my question.